# Python List: 1) How to print a list [not from index 0] to the end, dynamically?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list
`alphabets = ["A","B",'C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']`

I can print the whole thing
`print(alphabets)`

but I want to print it to the end, without starting from index 0
`print(alphabets[1:9])`

This only works when I know the end index.

So, considering that the list may change, how do I print the from any point other than index 0 and print to the end without changing the code as well?

Comment: `print(alphabets[1:])`

Comment: This gives a really good explanation of list slicing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave the end index empty and it will be interpreted as "until the end of the sequence":

```
alphabets = ["A","B",'C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']

print(alphabets[1:])

#output
['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
```